# GLM - multiplication operation

Tags: matrix-multiplication, glm-math

In GLM, the following operator is invoked when a matrix is multiplied by a vector:

```
template<typename T, qualifier Q>
GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER typename mat<2, 2, T, Q>::col_type operator*
(
    mat<2, 2, T, Q> const& m,
    typename mat<2, 2, T, Q>::row_type const& v
)
{
    return vec<2, T, Q>(
        m[0][0] * v.x + m[1][0] * v.y,
        m[0][1] * v.x + m[1][1] * v.y);
}
```

This function would return the correct value if the values of the matrix could be accessed with `matrix[col][row]`, but I have already tested that - the values of the matrix are given by `matrix[row][col]`. The following code returns the result {23, 34}, but the correct result would be {17, 39}:

```
glm::mat2 mat2    {
    1.f, 2.f,
    3.f, 4.f
};
glm::vec2 vec2    { 5.f, 6.f };
glm::vec2 result  { mat2 * vec2 };
```

The number of columns from the left matrix must match the number of rows from the right matrix, so I do not understand why the following function exists, but this function returns the correct result ({17, 39}) for me:

```
template<typename T, qualifier Q>
GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER typename mat<2, 2, T, Q>::row_type operator*
(
    typename mat<2, 2, T, Q>::col_type const& v,
    mat<2, 2, T, Q> const& m
)
{
    return vec<2, T, Q>(
        v.x * m[0][0] + v.y * m[0][1],
        v.x * m[1][0] + v.y * m[1][1]);
}
```

and is called by `vec2 * mat2`.

I can not imagine that GLM has such a big bug, so I'm sure I'll miss something - do I have to define something in front of the header or what could this strange behavior be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The following code returns the result {23, 34}, but the correct result would be {17, 39}:

No, it isn't.

`glm::mat`rices are column-major. This means that, in your definition, `1.f, 2.f` is the first *column* of your matrix. When you do `matrix * vector`, you get the *rows* of the matrix times the *columns* of the vector. The first row of your matrix is `1.f, 3.f`, which when dot-producted by `5.f, 6.f` is 23.

Which is what you get.

Comment: I did not know that there are implementations of matrices where the rows and columns are reversed, so column-major is used. Phew, I do not like the column-major implementation at all, that's completely unintuitive for me and now I always have to think about two corners. Well, maybe I'll get used to it or implement a small matrix wrapper, thanks anyway, that helps me a lot further :).